# Poisson process: the probability of no arrival and no action at each time

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Suppose that a customer arrives according to a Poisson process at a rate $\lambda$. The time is denoted by $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$. At each time, the probability that a customer has not arrived is $1 - F(t)$, where $F=1-\exp(-\lambda t)$. When a customer arrives, he buys a product w.p. $p(t)$ and does not buy w.p. $p(t)$. In any case, the customer exits instantly after the purchase decision is made. What is the probability that no customer made a purchase at $T$?

If $p(t)=1, \forall t$, then it is just a probability that no customer has arrived, so it is $\exp(-\lambda T)$. My hunch is that
$$
\exp(-\lambda \int_0^T p(t))dt,
$$
but I am not sure how to formally show this.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Specifically, it's not clear what $t$ is nor is it  clear what "made a purchase at $T$" mean.  How long does a customer stay?  If they stay for a millionth of a second, presumably they don't buy anything, right?

Comment: I added some explanation. I'm thinking about a situation in which each customer randomly arrives and buys or not w.p. $p(t)$, and then he is done. Thus, the probability that I want to derive is that at time $T$, (i) no one arrived or (ii) everyone who arrived did not make a purchase.

Comment: I don't see how any of that is clearer than what you wrote before.  In any case, all of my questions are still open.

Comment: Thee customer does not stay. When arrived, he makes the purchase w.p. $p(t)$. Another way to put this is that the arrival consists of two stage: a customer arrives at each t according to Poisson and only a fraction $p(t)$ of them actually arrives. In this case, I'm interested in the probability that no customer has actually arrived

Comment: The probability that a customer arrives at a specific time $t$ is $0$.  You could try to look at an interval $[t,t+\Delta t]$ where arrival is poisson with a scaled mean.  Perhaps that's more the sort of thing you had in mind.

Comment: Yes, so I was thinking the probability of no purchase from time 0 to time $T$. If $p(t)=1, \forall t$, then this reduces to a standard Poisson process and the probability of no purchase up until time $T$ is $1 - F(T)$, where $F(T)= 1 - \exp(-\lambda T)$. If $p(t)=0, \forall t$, then the probability of no purchase up until $T$ is $1$. In a similar vein, if $p(t)=1/2$, then the probability is $1 - F(T; \lambda/2)$. Since half of the customer who arrived does not make a purchase, this is essentially scaling down the arrival rate by half. My question is, what if $p(t)$ is not constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Big\{[t_{i-1},t_i),s_i\Big\}_{i=1}^n$ be a uniform tagged partition of $[0,T]$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length $\Delta t=\frac{T-0}{n}$.

The number of customers who arrive on $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ is $\text{Poisson}\left(\lambda\Delta t\right)$, and these customers can be grouped into two distinct categories: those who purchase an item and those who do not. If $n$ is large we expect $\lambda p(s_i)\Delta t$ customers to purchase and item and $\lambda (1-p(s_i))\Delta t$ to leave the establishment empty handed.

In this way we see that our Poisson process on $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ splits, and the number of customers who purchase an item on $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ is approximately $\text{Poisson}\left(\lambda p(s_i)\Delta t\right)$.

Observe now that the total of customers who purchase an item on $[0,T]$ is approximately  $\text{Poisson}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda p(s_i)\Delta t\right)$ which becomes $\text{Poisson}\left(\lambda\int_0^T p(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)$ after taking $n$ to $+\infty$.

So, the probability nobody purchased an item is exactly what you proposed: $\exp\left(-\lambda \int_0^T p (t)\mathrm{d}t \right)$